# Enabling extra routing layers in Eagle (paid version) PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers

I started a PCB design in the freeware version of Eagle, now I have the full version, but it won't let me route tracks to the extra route layers (i.e: only top and bottom). Starting a new design in the paid version gives 5 extra routing layers.

Any ideas how to enable these layers on designs that were started in the freeware version?

Any help is appreciated

Tom

Answer (score 12):

As Dave posted in his answer (+1), you need to enable the layers in the DRC. Here's an example:

[image]

And from the EAGLE help file (which is an excellent resource by the way):

> ### Layers
>
> The Layers tab defines which signal layers the board actually uses,
>   how thick the copper and isolation layers are, and what kinds of vias
>   can be placed (note that this applies only to actual vias; so even if
>   no via from layer 1 to 16 has been defined in the layer setup, pads
>   will always be allowed).
>
> The layer setup is defined by the string in the "Setup" field. This
>   string consists of a sequence of layer numbers, separated by one of
>   the characters '*' or '+', where '*' stands for core material (also
>   known as FR4 or something similar) and '+' stands for prepreg (or any
>   other kind of isolation material). The actual core and prepreg
>   sequence has no meaning to EAGLE other than varying the color in the
>   layer display at the top left corner of this tab (the actual
>   multilayer setup always needs to be worked out with the board
>   manufacturer). The vias are defined by enclosing a sequence of layers
>   with (...). So the setup string
>
> `(1*16)`
>
> would mean a two layer board, using layers 1 and 16 and vias going
>   through the entire board (this is also the default value). When
>   building a multilayer board the setup could be something like
>
> `((1*2)+(15*16))`
>
> which is a four layer board with layer pairs 1/2 and 15/16 built on
>   core material and vias drilled through them, and finally the two layer
>   pairs pressed together with prepreg between them, and vias drilled all
>   the way through the entire board. Besides vias that go through an
>   entire layer stack (which are commonly referred to as buried vias in
>   case they have no connection to the Top and Bottom layer) there can
>   also be vias that are not drilled all the way through a layer stack,
>   but rather end at a layer inside that stack. Such vias are known as
>   blind vias and are defined in the "Setup" string by enclosing a
>   sequence of layers with [t:...:b], where t and b are the layers up to
>   which that via will go from the top or bottom side, respectively. A
>   possible setup with blind vias could be
>
> `[2:1+((2*3)+(14*15))+16:15]`
>
> which is basically the previous example, with two additional outer
>   layers that are connected to the next inner layers by blind vias. It
>   is also possible to have only one of the t or b parameters, so for
>   instance
>
> `[2:1+((2*3)+(15*16))]`
>
> would also be a valid setup. Finally, blind vias are not limited to
>   starting at the Top or Bottom layer, but may also be used in inner
>   layer stacks, as in
>
> `[2:1+[3:2+(3*4)+5:4]+16:5]`
>
> A blind via from layer a to layer b also implements all possible blind
>   vias from layer a to all layers between layers a and b, so
>
> `[3:1+2+(3*16)]`
>
> would allow blind vias from layer 1 to 2 as well as from 1 to 3.

Answer (score 4):

You need to go into the DRC dialog and define your stackup there before you can route tracks on the additional layers. Read the documentation, because the syntax is a little tricky with regard to the definition of blind and buried vias. You probably don't want them, but you don't want to accidentally enable them.