# Understanding PCB layer stack-up shorthand notation [2:(1(2+345*67)*16):7]

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, via, pcb-layers

I was given a PCB layer stackup specification like this:

```
[2:(1(2+345*67)*16):7]
```

For an 8 layer blind via setup.

Could someone provide a reference to decode this shorthand notation?
What is the proper name of this shorthand notation?
How widely used is this notation?

Update: apparently it's from Eagle CAD's DRC (design rule check) dialog.

Comment: This appears to be Eagle-specific. I have never seen this notation before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reposting this from an [old answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/144617/15805). I'm not sure this is a duplicate, because the [old question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/144614/15805) specifically asks about Eagle CAD layers.

The description on the notation is below. However, it appears the notation you got is flawed. The presence of the numbers '345' and '67' can't be correct.

It doesn't seem unreasonable to assume the '345' is '3*4*5' and the same for '67' being '6*7'. The corrected specification is:

> [2:(1*(2+3*4*5*6*7)*16):7]

If true, your stack up looks like this:

[image]

There are blind, buried, and standard vias.

---

From the EAGLE help file, (which uses the same layer notation you're dealing with):

> ### Layers
>
> The Layers tab defines which signal layers the board actually uses,
>   how thick the copper and isolation layers are, and what kinds of vias
>   can be placed (note that this applies only to actual vias; so even if
>   no via from layer 1 to 16 has been defined in the layer setup, pads
>   will always be allowed).
>
> The layer setup is defined by the string in the "Setup" field. This
>   string consists of a sequence of layer numbers, separated by one of
>   the characters '*' or '+', where '*' stands for core material (also
>   known as FR4 or something similar) and '+' stands for prepreg (or any
>   other kind of isolation material). The actual core and prepreg
>   sequence has no meaning to EAGLE other than varying the color in the
>   layer display at the top left corner of this tab (the actual
>   multilayer setup always needs to be worked out with the board
>   manufacturer). The vias are defined by enclosing a sequence of layers
>   with (...). So the setup string
>
> `(1*16)`
>
> would mean a two layer board, using layers 1 and 16 and vias going
>   through the entire board (this is also the default value). When
>   building a multilayer board the setup could be something like
>
> `((1*2)+(15*16))`
>
> which is a four layer board with layer pairs 1/2 and 15/16 built on
>   core material and vias drilled through them, and finally the two layer
>   pairs pressed together with prepreg between them, and vias drilled all
>   the way through the entire board. Besides vias that go through an
>   entire layer stack (which are commonly referred to as buried vias in
>   case they have no connection to the Top and Bottom layer) there can
>   also be vias that are not drilled all the way through a layer stack,
>   but rather end at a layer inside that stack. Such vias are known as
>   blind vias and are defined in the "Setup" string by enclosing a
>   sequence of layers with [t:...:b], where t and b are the layers up to
>   which that via will go from the top or bottom side, respectively. A
>   possible setup with blind vias could be
>
> `[2:1+((2*3)+(14*15))+16:15]`
>
> which is basically the previous example, with two additional outer
>   layers that are connected to the next inner layers by blind vias. It
>   is also possible to have only one of the t or b parameters, so for
>   instance
>
> `[2:1+((2*3)+(15*16))]`
>
> would also be a valid setup. Finally, blind vias are not limited to
>   starting at the Top or Bottom layer, but may also be used in inner
>   layer stacks, as in
>
> `[2:1+[3:2+(3*4)+5:4]+16:5]`
>
> A blind via from layer a to layer b also implements all possible blind
>   vias from layer a to all layers between layers a and b, so
>
> `[3:1+2+(3*16)]`
>
> would allow blind vias from layer 1 to 2 as well as from 1 to 3.

Comment: In your answer the + refers to both core and prepreg.  Did a character get mangled?

Comment: @Bryce Yeah, I had to escape the * characters.

Comment: I think Eagle always uses layer 16 for the bottom, so on an 8 layer board you would have layers 1-7, and 16. Hence on a 2-layer board you have [1*16]

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yeah, that's right, I forgot about that. Just a naming convention, but still accurate.